# Load Video/Audio html by chunks

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, streaming

I have an Node.js server for serve audio and video files by stream.
This server accepts ranges (byte serving).

My goal is request an audio or video from the client (browser) and only fetch an small chunk of the file (320kb for example) and before finish of reproduce this chunk, request the next range of the file and repeat the process until the file is totally consumed.

how can achive this? Can i achive this with Audio/Video API html5? how can i define the size of the chunk that i want consume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have to do anything - all major modern browsers will support range requests automatically if you use the  tag, for example, and request the file in 'chunks', and if your server supports range requests as you say.

You can see it in action by using the developer tools in your browser and observing the network tab.

I'm not aware, however, of a way to specify the chunk size yourself - if that is really important to you, you could use the Media Source Extension mechanism which essentially allows you handle the download, and any manipulation you want to do to the streamed file, before you pass it to the browser video player.

One thing to be aware of - for mp4 files, the header need to be at the start of the file to enable you to stream it. By default it is at the end so you need to move it - there are many tools which will allow you do this. See here for example:

- http://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/